# Dropdown Button only working when clicking on very edges

Tags: html, dropdown

I have been following Web Dev Simplified's tutorial on dropdowns. My dropdown works, but you can only dropdown when you are selecting the div outside the button (on the very edges of the button). When you click on the text, it doesn't do anything.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <style>
    .content {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .dropdown.active>.dropdown-menu+.content {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="dropdown" data-dropdown>
    <button class="dropdown-menu" id="phoneButton" data-dropdown-button>
      <h4>Therapy</h4>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-angle-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="content" id="contentPhone">
      <a href="person-centred.html">Person Centred Therapy</a>
      <a href="play.html">Play Therapy</a>
      <a href="music.html">Music Therapy</a>
      <a href="art.html">Art Therapy</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    document.addEventListener("click", e => {
      const isDropdownButton = e.target.matches("[data-dropdown-button]")
      if (!isDropdownButton && e.target.closest("[data-dropdown]") != null) return

      let currentDropdown
      if (isDropdownButton) {
        currentDropdown = e.target.closest("[data-dropdown]")
        currentDropdown.classList.toggle("active")
      }

      document.querySelectorAll("[data-dropdown].active").forEach(dropdown => {
        if (dropdown === currentDropdown) return
        dropdown.classList.remove("active")
      })
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I wrote some JS. Actually the problem is e.target.matches(). Here it just takes button. but your content has h4 tag. You are accessing a data attribute with e.target.matches() and if you click on this h4 tag nothing will be triggered. Therefore, by directly selecting the button id, it will include all the elements in the button.**

```js
document.getElementById('phoneButton').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        currentDropdown = e.target.closest("[data-dropdown]");
      currentDropdown.classList.toggle("active");
   });
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked! I just had to add the data-dropdown-button to the h4!

Comment: Glad it worked.  Can you mark the problem as solved?  I can gain some reputation :) @InterPixel

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad I will now (I'm a beginner to stack overflow)